# why my code do not insert data to database in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I have to make how to fix them? 
Please note that the code is still complete and I have entered some print statements for checking. 
my table in database 
database: sharefile
tablet: members

id, mem_first_name,mem_last_name,mem_email,mem_password,mem_birthday

singup.jsp

```
    <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="jsp.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
    <%!
    public static String validateEmail(String email){
        String error = "";
        if(email.isEmpty()){
            error ="This field is required.";
        }else if(email.length() > 32)
        {

            error ="This field cannot exceed the length of 32.";
        }else if(email.matches("\\w+(\\.\\w+)*@\\w+\\.\\w(2,4)")){
            error = "Invalid email.";
        }
        return error;
    }
    public static String validatePassword(String password){
        String error = "";
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            error ="This field is required.";
        }else if(password.length() > 24){

            error ="This field cannot exceed the length of 24.";
        }
        return error;
    }
    public static String validateBirthday(String birthday){
        String error = "";
        if(birthday.isEmpty()){
            error ="This field is required.";
        }else if(!birthday.matches("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}/\\d{4}")) {
            error = "Invalid date format. MM/dd/yyyy";


        }else{
            try{
                java.util.Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(birthday);
                if(d.after(new java.util.Date())){
                    error = "Invalid date.";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                error = "Invalid date.";
            }

        }
        return error;
    }

        public static long insertUser(Connection c, String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String birthday){

            long id = -1;

            try{
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO members (mem_first_name,mem_last_name,mem_email,mem_password,mem_birthday) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setString(1,fname);
                ps.setString(2,lname);
                ps.setString(3,email);
                ps.setString(4,password);
                java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(birthday).getTime());
                ps.setDate(5,d);
                ps.execute();
                ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                if(rs.next()){
                    id = rs.getLong(1);
                }
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            return id;
        }

    %>

    <%
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String fname = request.getParameter("first_name");
String lname = request.getParameter("last_name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String birthday = request.getParameter("birthday");
    String email_error = "",password_error = "",birthday_error = "";
    if(email==null)
    {
        email = "";
        password = "";
        birthday = "";
        fname = "";
        lname = "";

    }else{
        email_error = validateEmail(email);
        password_error = validatePassword(password);
        birthday_error = validateBirthday(birthday);
        if(email_error.isEmpty() && password_error.isEmpty() || birthday_error.isEmpty())
        {
            Connection c = MySQL.connect();
            if(c!=null){
                long id = insertUser(c,email,password,fname,lname,birthday);   
                if(id!=1){
                    session.setAttribute(Template.USER_ID, id);
                }else{
                    email_error = "That email is already in use.";
                }
                }
        }

    }

    %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#birthday").datepicker();
});

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign up <small>It's free!</small></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address" value="<%=email%>"><%=email_error %>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password"><%=password_error %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Birthday" value="<%=birthday%>"><%=birthday_error %>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

MySQL.java

```
    package jsp;

import java.sql.*;

public class MySQL {
    public static Connection connect() {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sharefile","root","123456");
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;

    }

    }
    public static boolean close(Connection c){
        try{
            c.close();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Template.java

```
    package jsp;

public class Template {

    public static final String USER_ID = "id";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been writing Java code for 15 years, and this may be the worst possible way I've see anyone try to accomplish this. This approach was a miserable idea then, and remains one today - maybe more so.

Stop. Now.

Take some time and learn about options for using databases in Java (mybatis, hibernate, JPA, anything but direct jdbc in jsp).

Take some more and learn about web development in Java and the options around that (struts, jsf, stripes, anything but a pile of crappy code dumped in a jsp file).

After that, come back and ask again.

Comment: thank you. But I have 2 month to make project Web Share File, like mediafire but it's simple than!

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

In above code...there is no need of creating a new instance.
What we do is basically we load the driver class into memory rather than creating a new instance.

So use like

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");